# Android retrieve a set of contacts similar to built in Contacts app

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm using code like the following, and on my phone it returns 4000+ rows, but on my phone I have 295 contacts in the Contacts app.

Whats going on here? I've been reading up on the contacts database, and I'm not yet familiar enough to figure this out.

Thanks!

```
    final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    final Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

    final int nameIdx = cur.getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME);
    final int idIdx = cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);

    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
      String name = cur.getString(nameIdx);
      String id = cur.getString(idIdx);
      contacts.add(new Contact(name, id));
    }
    cur.close();
```

Comment: Passing a `null` projection will return all the columns. [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html)

Comment: Yep.  Though, my question is about rows, not columns.

Comment: You probably want to use `ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = 1` as your `selection `argument

Comment: As I mentioned below I don't care if they have a phone number or not.  What I ended up doing is using IN_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY=1 as my selection.

Comment: And the downvote is because why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to filter for contacts that have IN_VISIBLE_GROUP = 1.

```
    final String selection = String.format("%s = ?", ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP);
    final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { "1" };
    final Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

I also tried IN_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY = 1 which also worked well but is only supported on Lollipop (21) and newer.

Answer (score 1):

I am had a similar problem in Android 6. Some of the contacts were not showing up when you query using

```
ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP = 1
```

Then I changed the selection to

```
String selection = "in_default_directory = 1"; // Aka ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.IN_DEFAULT_DIRECTORY
String[] selectionArgs = null;
String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
Cursor nameCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

Now it returns all the contacts as per Contact app.